# C# UWP Geolocation, access denied

Tags: c#, location, uwp, coordinates, access-denied

everybody.

I am trying to get current user's location in C# UWP application.

```
var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
var pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
var latitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
var longitude = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
```

But I get the error:

*An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Your App does not have permission to access location data. Make sure you have defined ID_CAP_LOCATION in the application manifest and that on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings > Location.
Additional information: Access is denied.*

In Package.appxmanifest I have these items checked:
Internet (Client & Server) - checked,
Internet (Client) - checked,
Location - checked.

How can I set permission in local machine?

Comment: "*... and that on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings > Location*", have you checked that?

Comment: I am debugging it on my local machine...and in Simulator, not on phone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue. In Windows 10, in Location privacy settings my Location services wasn't on. So I turned it on, and now it is working.

Comment: If you have "PermissionError: [WinError -2147024891] Access Denied" while using winrt or winsdk you MUST apply this answer AND turn on the setting to grant applications access to your location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check either you are allowed to access location services or not ?
You can handle this using [RequestAccessAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.requestaccessasync#Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geolocator_RequestAccessAsync) method of [GeoLocater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator) Class in UWP.

```
        Geolocator geoLocator = new Geolocator();
        GeolocationAccessStatus accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

        if ( accessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            // Put all your Code here to access location services
            Geoposition geoposition = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            var position = geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position;
            var latlong = string.Format("lat:{0}, long:{1}", position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
        }
        else if (accessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied)
        {
               // No Accesss
        }
        else
        {
        }
```