# UWP/C# 'Access is denied' Exception when setting Geofence

Tags: c#, uwp, location, geofence

I have a .NET 5 Console Application for which I used following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) the
'.NET 5: Use the Target Framework Moniker option'. This means my project file looks like this at the moment:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.18362</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I then tried access the Location Api using `new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync()` which works as expected.
To my understanding, there are certain UWP APIs that I can only use if my app has a package identity. So I created a an Application Packaging Project that references as application my Console App. I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) for packaging the whole project as msix package. This now works well and I can still access the current geoposition as expected.

However, I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/set-up-a-geofence) for setting up a geofence in UWP and as soon as I try to register a geofence or even register an event handler for triggered geofences I get a

`One or more errors occurred. (Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)))`

exception. My capabilities in the manifest file are defined as following:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

Before I try setting a geofence or registering an event handler, I always call `await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync()` and only continue execute the action if this method returns Allowed which is every time. This means the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480248/c-sharp-uwp-geolocation-access-denied) does not help me.

Is there any possibility to make sure that there is nothing wrong with how I defined my capabilities? For example, is there a way to check my capabilities at runtime? So far, I did not find anything on that topic.
Or is there a problem with my principal assumption that as soon as my Console App has a package id because it's packaged as msix, I can access features like Geofencing that would not be accessible to me otherwise?

After having checked that I have access to the location with a call to `await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync()` I for example try to execute the following code:

```
GeofenceMonitor.Current.GeofenceStateChanged += this.OnGeofenceStateChanged;
```

and immediately receive the exception.

EDIT: I have now also tried to use the same Code in a UWP App. There, it works like a charm and I noticed that I get a Pop-Up when `RequestLocation` is executed asking me to grant the app permission to access the location. I have never received a similar Pop-Up in my console application. I thought this might be because of a lacking UI Thread.

I have now also tried to use a WPF application instead of the Console application to test whether a lack of UI thread might be the problem. However, I have the same problem in the WPF application (of course then also packaged as .msix) as I do in my console application.